# Issue Django, insert session login user data in database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Actually I want to insert session login user data in database but I when I put this code I get all register user in Dropdown but I want to only current login user data not all and also I want to hide this field value.please help.

model.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User     


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=200)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=29.99)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100,\
                                            null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update_defaults = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_product", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

view.py

```
class DealsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

        fields = ['title','description','category','price','sale_price','slug','active','update_defaults','user']
```

last field user where I want to Insert current session login user data..how..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude it from `ModelForm`,

Like,

```
class DealsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

        ...
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Then override form save method,

```
class DealsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Product
         exclude = ('user',)

    def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         obj = super(DealsForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
         obj.user = request.user #store here users data 
         obj.save()
```

If you exclude any field in `ModelForm` then this field will not rendered on template.